# C++: Way to create the equivalent of Arduino 'byte' in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, class, arduino

Background:

I am programming an [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx). I can't stand the Arduino IDE, so I prefer using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) for writing code. However, I have found all of the options available online for using Xcode to actually upload sketches to Arduino to be convoluted at best and have not been successful in trying to implement them.

Current Method:

What currently works well for me is to use Xcode strictly as a debugger, and 'creating' stripped down versions of Arduino classes when I need them so the debugger doesn't freak out when I put in lines of code specific to Arduino. For example, I have a Serial class in my Xcode project which has the following functions, which work just fine:

```
void Serial::print(int myInt)
{
    cout << myInt;
}

void Serial::println(int myInt)
{
    cout << myInt << endl;
}
```

I do the same for strings, and whatever other standard [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) datatype I may need to print.

This way, any time I want to put `Serial.print` within a function in another class I'm working on, I can debug strictly from within Xcode without opening the Arduino IDE. I can also create a "fake" class for `pinMode`, etc.

Issue:

I would like to do this with the `byte` datatype used in the Arduino environment. I am taking an object-oriented approach to this program, and it threatens to eat up the precious RAM on my little Arduino. So, in order to save space, I'm converting all my `int`s to `byte`s and so forth.

But, I assume (and my compiler tells me) that I can't subclass `char`, or `int`, or any other basic types. I don't see how I can start using statements like "`byte a = 2`" or something similar with my current (somewhat convoluted) work-around method.

Essentially, I want to trick Xcode into thinking `byte` is the same thing as `int` for all intents and purposes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typedefs. (By the way, it's **not Xcode who you will be fooling, but the compiler.**)

```
typedef int byte;
```

or

```
typedef uint8_t byte;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `typedef` keyword:

```
typedef int byte;
```

But `int` types are usually larger than a single byte. What you *really* probably want is:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably save yourself a lot of effort by reusing [ncore](https://github.com/maniacbug/ncore) which implements the Arduino hardware abstraction layer for Macs.

Even if you want to do this by hand it's worth taking a look at ncore. It defines byte using:

```
typedef uint8_t byte;
```

(in fact this is exactly how the libraries bundled with the Arduino IDE define it too!)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I tried just throwing the ncore folder into my XCode project and got all sorts of errors. The Readme seems to indicate ncore is best used from the command line, which is a level of complexity I neither need nor want to deal with just yet.